# error al hacer procedimiento con cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Intento hacer esto

```
CREATE PROCEDURE temporal( IN temp INT)
BEGIN

 DECLARE maxima INT
 SELECT MAX(ventas) FROM vendedor INTO maxima;
 CREATE TABLE ven_temp AS SELECT id_vendedor FROM vendedor;
 WHERE ventas=maxima;
 COMMIT;
 END;
```

me marca:

> ```
> error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax 
> to use near 'SELECT max(ventas) FROM vendedor INTO maxima' at line 5
> ```

quito `"."` y comas y sigue igual no se a que se deba

creo que puede ser por la version pero no se como se haga a la version que tengo uso esta

Versión de PHP: 5.5.38
phpmyadmin Acerca de esta versión: 4.5.1

Comment: ¿Dónde está el cursor?

Comment: Tienes al menos un error de sintaxis: `CREATE TABLE ven_temp AS SELECT id_vendedor FROM vendedor;
 WHERE ventas=maxima;` no puedes poner `;`antes del `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
DECLARE maxima INT;
SET maxima = (SELECT MAX(ventas) FROM vendedor);
```

También puedes verificar que tu consulta es correcta.

Saludos y comenta cualquier

Comment: me sale esto:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET maxima=(SELECT MAX(ventas) FROM vendedor)' at line 5

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE temporal( IN temp INT)
BEGIN

 DECLARE maxima INT
 SET maxima=(SELECT MAX(ventas) FROM vendedor);
 CREATE TABLE ven_temp AS SELECT id_vendedor FROM vendedor;
 WHERE ventas=maxima;
 COMMIT;
 END;

Comment: Prueba a añadirle " ; " al final del "declare" o Probar la solución de pablo

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta que después del   
**CREATE TABLE ven_temp AS SELECT id_vendedor FROM vendedor;**
 tienes puesto ";" antes del **WHERE ventas=maxima;**

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis correcta de `select into` es

```
select columna1, columna2,... columnaN into var1, var2,...varN from tablaX
```

Aplicado a tu código:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE temporal( IN temp INT)
BEGIN

 DECLARE maxima INT
 SELECT MAX(ventas) INTO maxima FROM vendedor;
 CREATE TABLE ven_temp AS SELECT id_vendedor FROM vendedor;
 WHERE ventas=maxima;
 COMMIT;
 END;
```